# What specific criteria must a custom built vehicle meet in order to drive on public roads?

Tags: united-states, insurance, vehicle, regulations, michigan

Assuming in the state of Michigan, I have seen [this Secretary of State web page on assembled vehicles](https://www.michigan.gov/sos/0,4670,7-127-1585_1587_1588-25476--,00.html), however, the two forms attached ([BFS-72](https://www.michigan.gov/documents/BFS-72__09-03__83315_7.pdf)) and ([TR-54](https://www.michigan.gov/documents/TR-54_38480_7.pdf)) seem very basic and non-technical for the most part. My question is is it really that easy to build a vehicle that meets the criteria, if so, are there any restrictions as far as obtaining insurance for such a custom-built vehicle, and lastly would it be able to be driven out-of-state?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is is it really that easy to build a vehicle that meets the criteria

That's not a legal question.

> are there any restrictions as far as obtaining insurance for such a
>   custom-built vehicle,

That depends on each insurance company's coverage offerings.

> and lastly would it be able to be driven out-of-state?

That depends on the laws of states other than Michigan regarding the licensing of custom built cars and the coverage of insurance companies licensed in those states.

Comment: By "Really that easy" I mean are there any further legal requirements, i.e. max allowable stopping distance from a certain speed, brightness of lights, etc. - and if so, what are they, which ones are applicable to a self-built car vs the mass-produced cars. As far as the insurance, considering it's obligatory, are there any laws regarding offering availability for such cars? And for the other states, are there any noteworthy differences as far as the laws go? exceptions to be aware of? etc.

Comment: "further legal requirements..." Those should be determined by the SOS inspector who actually certifies the vehicle; ask MI SOS for more info on that. "Insurance":  insurance companies are private; they decide their own offerings, unless MI law somehow *requires* them to make offerings for custom built vehicles; ask MI DIFS. "Other states?: that's far too broad a question. You need to Google for the states you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

The sections of the Michigan Vehicle Code listed at the bottom of Form TR-54 (MCL. 257.685-686, 257.688-691, 257.697-697b, 257.705-711) provide more specific information about what the police officer will be looking for when they make their safety inspection.  You can read the [pertinent sections of the Michigan Vehicle Code](http://legislature.mi.gov/doc.aspx?mcl-300-1949-VI-EQUIPMENT) to find out more information.

Regarding the specific questions raised as a comment elsewhere, the requirements for headlamps are given in MCL 257.685, and those for brake systems are given in MCL 257.705 & 705a.